# working in apache's document root

Tags: apache

On Fedora or Ubuntu apache's documentroot is owned by root. Should I go in there as root and edit in this there? I don't like this, but I'm probably missing something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, I wouldn't recommend it, unless you only need to change something really quickly. Just use `chown` or `chmod` and give your non-root user privileges. Alternatively, you could make a symbolic link to a directory that you own. That's what I use for development.

Comment: Thanks, but in Fedora those links are not allowed

Comment: Of *course* you can create symbolic links in Fedora!  The only restrictions are 1) you can't link to a different partition, and 2) you need to configure Apache to follow symlinks.  But these are restrictions for *any* Linux, BSD or Mac platform - not just Fedora...

Answer (score 0):

I agree: you really *shouldn't* be editing files as "root", especially on a production system.

There are (at least) two good options:

1) Create a new group (e.g. "webadmin") and make your default document root owned by that group

2) Rely on virtualhosts, and secure each virtual host as appropriate:

https://serverfault.com/questions/224560/best-permissions-ownership-for-apache-document-root